# Concatenating JSON files in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a workflow that is spinning up a bunch of parallel lambda functions to batch process data quickly, which are hitting a service then writing the JSON response in a S3 bucket. As a result, I can have thousands of JSON files that are 5MB+.

Now, I need to aggregate all those files into a single JSON file that can returned to the requestor.

I was attempting to do this with the [MultiPart Upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjctsMPUapi.html) so I didn't have to download, process and re-upload the files. Instead, I could do it all solely in S3 by Copying the parts to a final file. This actually works great, but the problem is the result is no longer valid JSON because it is literally just sticking the files together and not merging the JSON arrays (see below).

For example:

**File 1:**

```
[
    {
    "foo": "bar1"
    },
    {
    "foo": "bar2"
    }
]
```

**File 2:**

```
[
    {
    "foo": "bar3"
    },
    {
    "foo": "bar4"
    }
]
```

**Result Of Multipart Upload:**

```
[
    {
    "foo": "bar1"
    },
    {
    "foo": "bar2"
    }
][
    {
    "foo": "bar3"
    },
    {
    "foo": "bar4"
    }
]
```

As you can see above, I now have invalid JSON with the end bracket for one file and the start bracket of another instead of a comma.

**Result I want:**

```
[
    {
    "foo": "bar1"
    },
    {
    "foo": "bar2"
    },
    {
    "foo": "bar3"
    },
    {
    "foo": "bar4"
    }
]
```

Now I am stuck on what to do. The 3GB RAM limitation means I may not be able to just open each file and build the final result in memory then write to S3 as it can easily be >3GB.

*Are there any options I am overlooking, or am I just going to have to write some nasty code to brute force it?*

The only thing I can think (that I really don't want to do) is to format the first file without an ending bracket, the middle files with no brackets and the last file with no start bracket.

```
Head file
[
    {
        "foo": "bar1"
    },
Any middle files
    {
        "foo": "bar2"
    },
Final file
    {
        "foo": "barN"
    }
]
```

So that when I do the join through the Multipart Copy it will be proper...

```
[
    {
        "foo": "bar1"
    },
    {
        "foo": "bar2"
    },
    {
        "foo": "barN"
    }
]
```

Comment: Are the foo/bar objects always a single key/value pair with the exact same key every time (and potentially different values)?

Comment: Yes. All of the files are created as the result of an API request, so they will all have the same schema.

Comment: I think you will have to do it they way you described, with manually removing the `[]` as appropriate. However you don't have to worry that much about hitting the memory limit, as you should only ever have a single file (one part of the multipart upload) loaded in memory. After the part upload is done, the memory can be freed.

Comment: @MilanCermak - I can probably make it more efficient by writing the response parts without the brackets and always have a trailing comma (the "middle file" approach above). Then I would just have to edit the first and last file as needed.

Comment: OK, if all of the files are essentially arrays of key=value pairs with the same key then maybe you could simply write the list of values to each file instead. That would make concatenating them simple and the resulting file would also be a list of values. Reading that would be simpler than reading a 3GB JSON file because you could stream the file and process line by line, rather than having to load the entire 3GB in one go to ensure that it's actually valid JSON (which is what a typical JSON parser would do).

Comment: Are you open to using other formats. [Amazon Ion](http://amzn.github.io/ion-docs/) looks very similar to JSON, and due to its lack of a trailer `,`, works well with this use-case.